# How to convert string data to json formated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting response from server in the following format:

```
[{"key":"Idle Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"4.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"6.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"4.15"}]},{"key":"Operational Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"20.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"18.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"19.45"}]}]
```

I need to convert this to json format so I used `JSON.parse`. This is what I got:

```
[{key:"Idle Time",values:[{x:"SADSA",y:"4.0"},{x:"FDDG",y:"6.0"},{x:"FF",y:"4.15"}]},{key:"Operational Time",values:[{x:"SADSA",y:"20.0"},{x:"FDDG",y:"18.0"},{x:"FF",y:"19.45"}]}]
```

But I want the following format:

```
[{key:"Idle Time",values:[{x:"SADSA",y:4.0},{x:"FDDG",y:6.0},{x:"FF",y:4.15}]},{key:"Operational Time",values:[{x:"SADSA",y:20.0},{x:"FDDG",y:18.0},{x:"FF",y:19.45}]}]
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"key":"Idle Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"4.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"6.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"4.15"}]},{"key":"Operational Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"20.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"18.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"19.45"}]}]')` gives me your desired result (with numbers represented as strings)

Comment: Do you have control on modifying response from server?

Comment: I dont want numbers as string

Comment: @ThumChoonTat can we change it in client side?

Comment: Go through the values and use `parseFloat` or `Number` to convert your `y` properties to numeric values

Comment: @laz klugjo suggestion will work

Comment: JSON.parse parses JSON to a javascript object, so, your terminology is way off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a `reviver` function of [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and convert numerical values to numbers.

> #### Using the reviver parameter
>
> If a `reviver` is specified, the value computed by parsing is *transformed* before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties (beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself) are individually run through the `reviver`. Then it is called, with the object containing the property being processed as `this`, and with the property name as a string, and the property value as arguments. If the `reviver` function returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) (or returns no value, for example, if execution falls off the end of the function), the property is deleted from the object. Otherwise, the property is redefined to be the return value.
>
> If the `reviver` only transforms some values and not others, be certain to return all untransformed values as-is, otherwise they will be deleted from the resulting object.

```js
var json = '[{"key":"Idle Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"4.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"6.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"4.15"}]},{"key":"Operational Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"20.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"18.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"19.45"}]}]',
    data = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => !isNaN(value) ? +value : value);
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, the elegance of your answers never fails to stun me.

Comment: its working great!! Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: it is as simple as this, it visits before converting the string to an meaningfull object all key/value pairs and perform the function (*reviver*) for each of them. the function basically checks if the value is not not-a-number and if so it uses an unary plus for getting a numerical value. for each other just takes the original value.

Comment: what `+value` will do here?

Comment: it is an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which converts a stringed number to a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertToNo(a){
    for (var i in a){
        if (!isNaN(a[i])) a[i] = parseFloat(a[i]);
        if (a[i].isArray()) return convertToNo(a[i]);
    }
}
var newObj = convertToNo(oldObj);
```

This loops through the array and change all strings to numbers.

Comment: Please don't use "JSON" when you actually mean "object". JSON is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can also work for you:

```js
var strJson = '[{"key":"Idle Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"4.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"6.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"4.15"}]},{"key":"Operational Time","values":[{"x":"SADSA","y":"20.0"},{"x":"FDDG","y":"18.0"},{"x":"FF","y":"19.45"}]}]';
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(strJson); 
var res = [];
parsedJSON.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.values.forEach((innerObj) => {
    innerObj.y = parseFloat(innerObj.y);
  });
  res.push(obj);
});
console.log(res);
```